# What came first: git subtree merge strategy or git submodule?

Tags: git, history, git-submodules, git-subtree

What is more recent invention — git subtree merge strategy (not the new git-subtree command) or git submodule command (or maybe underlying mechanism if there was a separate one symmetrical to git subtree command vs. merge strategy).

What was included in Git distribution release first?

Bonus points for links to relevant Git ML posts.

I tried do dig that info from Git commit history, but got lost somewhere in 2007-2008 for both features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subtree merge seems to be a tad older:

Introduced by Junio Hamano in Feb 2007 [`68faf68938ee943fc251c702f2027e4dfda354db`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68faf68938ee943fc251c702f2027e4dfda354db) »Add new merge stragety [sic] 'subtree'« (file `git-merge.sh`)

Git submodule was introduced in May 2007 by Lars Hjemli in commit [`70c7ac22de681a83621bda03e676348170c8d8a2`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/70c7ac22de681a83621bda03e676348170c8d8a2) »Add git-submodule command« (file `git-submodule.sh`)

To get the releases that first contained a certain feature, run `git describe --contains` on its commit.
For the above commits this means `v1.5.2-rc0` and `v1.5.3-rc0`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks. Care to name git releases that first included one and another?

Comment: @AlexanderGladysh: See my updated answer (v1.5.2-rc0 and v1.5.3-rc0)